# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.locals'; 'pygame' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So this problem is a bit strange for me. I wrote this piece of code to see if pygame works correctly.

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello World")
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

I saved this file as `pygame.py` and when I typed:

```
-python pygame.py
```

on the cmd it says:

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.locals'; 'pygame' is not a package
```

And if I type `-python` to the shell and then type `import pygame` it works like a charm.

So In summary: If I want to execute `pygame.py`, it does not see the module,
but it sees the module after typing `python` and `import pygame` (works without error).

The operating system is Windows.

Comment: you shouldn't name your python script `pygame.py`

Comment: I have just changed it nothing has changed

Comment: ok. maybe there is a `pygame.pyc` file now, since you tried to import it. check the directory for `pygame.pyc`

Comment: Worked ! But why ?

Comment: you installed `pygame` in your python directory, and since there were two files named `pygame`, the interpreter thought you were trying to import the module that **your** code was in, so it created a compiled python file (`.pyc`) so you could import it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Naming the file pygame.py makes the computer think of the file when importing, not the package. That is why it says pygame is not a package because pygame is the file.